# Maven cannot locate dependencies in local repo

Tags: maven

I have declared all spring dependencies in a project of type pom and installed it.

My project's pom that uses the common dependencies pom is as follows. But it seems maven is not using/cannot locate the dependencies pom

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.bookme</groupId>
    <artifactId>portal</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>portal</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bookme.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>    
    </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong pls?
Thanks

Comment: Please post the error message from Maven.

Comment: Have you install your dependency pom to local m2 repo?

Answer (score 2):

1. Have you install you dependency pom to you local m2 repository?
2. Add `scope` as `import` to you dependency pom. Look [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) for more details

> ```
> <dependencyManagement>
> <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.bookme.common</groupId>
>         <artifactId>common-dependencies</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0</version>
>         <type>pom</type>
>         <scope>import</scope>
>     </dependency>    
> </dependencies>
> </dependencyManagement>
> ```

Consider the following facts also

- Do not attempt to import a pom that is defined in a submodule of the
  current pom. Attempting to do that will result in the build failing
  since it won't be able to locate the pom.
- Never declare the pom importing a pom as the parent (or grandparent,
  etc) of the target pom. There is no way to resolve the circularity
  and an exception will be thrown.
- When referring to artifacts whose poms have transitive dependencies
  the project will need to specify versions of those artifacts as
  managed dependencies. Not doing so will result in a build failure
  since the artifact may not have a version specified. (This should be
  considered a best practice in any case as it keeps the versions of
  artifacts from changing from one build to the next).

Comment: Thanks, but adding <scope>import</scope> did not solve the problem. Here is my dependencies pom                                     <project>
    <groupId>com.bookme.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>common-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    
    <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

Comment: @SachinChandorkar: Please enhance the question with the dependency pom

Comment: Above is the example of the pom that contains the dependency. Altough I have installed it in local repo, maven does not locate it and my project build fails.